# How can I get rid of index dots on TabView with PageTabViewStyle in SwiftUI?

Tags: ios, swiftui, swiftui-tabview, pagetabviewstyle

I have the following code but can't seem to remove the dots at the bottom of the TabView.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @Environment(\.managedObjectContext) private var viewContext
    
    @State var users = ["Janice", "Emily", "Candice", "London", "Julia"]

    var body: some View {
        TabView {
            ForEach(users, id: \.self) { user  in
                UserCard(user: user)
            }
        }
        .tabViewStyle(PageTabViewStyle())
        .indexViewStyle(PageIndexViewStyle(backgroundDisplayMode: .never))
        .background(Color(.systemGroupedBackground))
    }
}

struct UserCard: View {
    
    let user: String
    
    var body: some View {
        Color.white
            .padding(30)
    }
}
```

I would have thought the PageIndexViewStyle(backgroundDisplayMode: .never) would remove the index dots but that is not working.  Is there any other way to get rid of them?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

try this:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @Environment(\.managedObjectContext) private var viewContext
    @State var users = ["Janice", "Emily", "Candice", "London", "Julia"]

    var body: some View {
        TabView {
            ForEach(users, id: \.self) { user  in
                UserCard(user: user)
            }
        }
        .tabViewStyle(.page(indexDisplayMode: .never))  // <--- here
        .background(Color(.systemGroupedBackground))
    }
}

struct UserCard: View {
    let user: String
    var body: some View {
        Text(user)
    }
}
```

Comment: thx.  Actually had to use .tabViewStyle(PageTabViewStyle(indexDisplayMode: .never)) for older swiftui version but works well.  thx.

Answer (score 9):

You have to add this:

```swift
.tabViewStyle(.page(indexDisplayMode: .never))
.indexViewStyle(PageIndexViewStyle(backgroundDisplayMode: .never))
```